# Best way to refresh table cells using Ajax/MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that will be fixed with the same number of rows and columns all the time. From time to time ( 2 minutes) I will read a table from a database and will compare de values.

Each 2 columns determines a status for a name/surname and after two minutes I will need to get the results again and compare the status.

Whats the best way to update this table without refreshing the page? I wont need to have pagination nor change the line numbers. I need to manipulate the data of the cells only.

I have found sources dividing each cell on ascx files, other using a single for the table, other using for columns. I'm here to ask whats the best approach for my need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ajax and Partial Views are going to be your best bet.

Comment: @mituw16 "Partial Views" for each cell ? I have more than 100 cells over the page.

Comment: @Dan-SP: that doesn't mean you need 100 partial views. Ideally, you should be able to craft one partial view that you just switch out the data on.

Comment: @ChrisPratt In fact, the data is enegible to show on any of them. So I think I will need to set a partial view for each.. hehe

Comment: @Dan-SP If you are designing a page where you think you need a partial view for each cell, then you are doing something horribly wrong. One partial view that houses your table, that gets refreshed via ajax is what you *should* be doing

Comment: @Mituw16 .. It is going to be a visual application ( shown on a TV) like a LAB and I need to refresh only the desired changes. Since I use status, I need to move one register from one column to another without refreshing the whole screen. Another point is that its a single table and as far as I know, its going to be hard to divide them into rows

Comment: @Mituw16, anyway, Im considering using the whole table inside a single partial view .. this will make me avoid the refresh of the screen to update the fields with ajax